# Retrieving data from a complex inconsistent JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm trying to set variables from a JSON object that I retrieve with a POST query. But the results aren't returned in the same order every time, so it doesn't always work. I'm not sure how to correctly set my variables with the array positions not remaining constant:

```
var idle = Example1.results[0].data[1].stats.count;
var waiting = Example1.results[1].data[0].stats.count;
```

(i.e. This works on example 1, but not example 2)

```
Example1 = {"results":[{"group":{"queueId":"someID"},"data":[{"metric":"oOnQueueUsers","qualifier":"INTERACTING","stats":{"count":2}},{"metric":"oOnQueueUsers","qualifier":"IDLE","stats":{"count":5}}]},{"group":{"queueId":"someID","mediaType":"voice"},"data":[{"metric":"oWaiting","stats":{"count":0}}]}]}

Example2 = {"results":[{"group":{"queueId":"someID","mediaType":"voice"},"data":[{"metric":"oWaiting","stats":{"count":1}}]},{"group":{"queueId":"someID"},"data":[{"metric":"oOnQueueUsers","qualifier":"INTERACTING","stats":{"count":4}},{"metric":"oOnQueueUsers","qualifier":"IDLE","stats":{"count":6}}]}]}
```

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript? Please update a tag with the related language. Also, there is no such thing as called JSON object. I think you mean JSON.

Comment: I oversimplified my question it seems. I'm using javascript (I'm new and self taught mostly) and I'm trying to parse individual data points from the JSON. My current workaround is converting it to a String instead of an Object and then I just search and slice the string, but I'd like to know the best way to get data from the object when the variable order is inconsistent

Comment: Please read the answer comments and it may help you to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot depend on the order being the same every time... or given your example data that each object doesn't even have the same properties... then you shouldn't search the resultant json for your data.

Rather then, you need to create your own data structure against which you will be able to search/index and then loop through your json, parsing each level within to decide how to map that particular element to your new data structure.

Here's an example of what you might could do...

```js
var exampleResults1 = {
  "results": [{
      "group": {
        "queueId": "someID"
      },
      "data": [{
          "metric": "oOnQueueUsers",
          "qualifier": "INTERACTING",
          "stats": {
            "count": 2
          }
        },
        {
          "metric": "oOnQueueUsers",
          "qualifier": "IDLE",
          "stats": {
            "count": 5
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "group": {
        "queueId": "someID",
        "mediaType": "voice"
      },
      "data": [{
        "metric": "oWaiting",
        "stats": {
          "count": 0
        }
      }]
    }
  ]
}

var newDataSource = {
  parseResults: function(resultObj) {
    resultObj.results.forEach(function(result) {
      var queueID = result.group.queueId;
      if (!newDataSource.hasOwnProperty(queueID)) {
        newDataSource[queueID] = {
          data: {}
        };
      }
      var newDataSourceQueue = newDataSource[queueID];

      result.data.forEach(function(dataObj) {
        var metric = dataObj.metric;
        if (!newDataSourceQueue.data.hasOwnProperty(metric)) {
          newDataSourceQueue.data[metric] = {};
        }
        var queueMetric = newDataSourceQueue.data[metric];

        var qualifier = "noQualifier";
        if (dataObj.hasOwnProperty("qualifier")) {
          qualifier = dataObj.qualifier;
        }
        queueMetric[qualifier] = {};
        var metricQualifier = queueMetric[qualifier];

        var statKeys = Object.keys(dataObj.stats);
        statKeys.forEach(function(stat) {
          if (!metricQualifier.hasOwnProperty(stat)) {
            metricQualifier[stat] = dataObj.stats[stat];
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
};

newDataSource.parseResults(exampleResults1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(newDataSource));
console.log("IDLE Count = " + newDataSource["someID"]["data"]["oOnQueueUsers"]["IDLE"]["count"]);
```

Running this code, you should be able to see what the new data structure looks like after its been populated with values from your original json object.  Notice how the keys of the objects are values from the original json.

My example code here doesn't take into account all data points in your example result sets... but should be enough to illustrate that you need to understand the data you are getting back and be able to come up with a consolidated data structure to encapsulate it using property keys that come from the actual returned results.

Comment: Note... other answer suggests find/some functions to get the pieces out of your code.   You can force it that way...  but if you ever have qualifiers show up in more than one metric, or if you ever need to know what queueID goes with which data set etc... then using the raw json as your data set and performing raw array/string parse/search will become very cumbersome.... you might could make it work, but the resultant solution wont be easily maintainable should data/requirements change in the future

Answer (score 0):

You can use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to get the result you want.

```js
const example1 = { results: [ { group: { queueId: "someID" }, data: [ { metric: "oOnQueueUsers", qualifier: "INTERACTING", stats: { count: 2 }, }, { metric: "oOnQueueUsers", qualifier: "IDLE", stats: { count: 5 } }, ], }, { group: { queueId: "someID", mediaType: "voice" }, data: [{ metric: "oWaiting", stats: { count: 0 } }], }, ], }; 

const example2 = { results: [ { group: { queueId: "someID", mediaType: "voice" }, data: [{ metric: "oWaiting", stats: { count: 1 } }], }, { group: { queueId: "someID" }, data: [ { metric: "oOnQueueUsers", qualifier: "INTERACTING", stats: { count: 4 }, }, { metric: "oOnQueueUsers", qualifier: "IDLE", stats: { count: 6 } }, ], }, ], };

const idle1 = example1.results
  .find(a => a.data.some(d => d.qualifier === "IDLE"))
  .data.find(b => b.qualifier === "IDLE").stats.count;

const waiting1 = example1.results
  .find(a => a.data.some(d => d.metric === "oWaiting"))
  .data.find(b => b.metric === "oWaiting").stats.count;

const idle2 = example2.results
  .find(a => a.data.some(d => d.qualifier === "IDLE"))
  .data.find(b => b.qualifier === "IDLE").stats.count;

const waiting2 = example2.results
  .find(a => a.data.some(d => d.metric === "oWaiting"))
  .data.find(b => b.metric === "oWaiting").stats.count;

console.log({ idle1 }, { waiting1 }, { idle2 }, { waiting2 });
```

Comment: too true....  this will find what you want... but becomes extremely cumbersome if/when you run into situations where things like "qualifiers" can show up within more than one "metric".   It didn't show up in his example set, but based on what it appears to be data for, I could easily see how it might happen.

Comment: @DynasticSponge, do you mean if `qualifier: "IDLE"` also exists in the `metric:oWaiting`? If this is the case, OP may provide more info on how he chooses which `IDLE` he needs.

Comment: yeah.. that's exactly the case... not saying it couldn't still be handled... but the code would get even more "fun" to read if say someone else came along 6mos later and had to deal with it.  S'why I ultimately think searching for keywords/values is not the best solution but rather transforming into a consistent data set is more adaptable/maintainable solution

Comment: @DynasticSponge, what you are doing is trying to fix a XY problem. If OP want to have a more maintainable solution, he should reconstruct his JSON before sending it like what you do instead of manipulating it after receiving it.

Comment: He stated that he's sending a POST message and having to deal with the response being inconsistent.  The external API is going to give him whatever its going to give him.